# Why static_cast not working for cv::Rect

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, c++14

I am trying to create a cv::Rect object

why `cv::Rect(100,100,100,100)`; works
but `static_cast<cv::Rect>(100,100,100,100)`; fails ?

I understand first one is a constructor, and second one is simply attempting to typecast the parameters to `cv::Rect` object.

Is there a way I can use `static_cast` here ?

Comment: second it a way to typecast expression 100,100,100,100 to cv::Rect, which  fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, `(100,100,100,100)` is the *parameter list* for the `cv::Rect` *constructor*.

In the second case, `(100,100,100,100)` is an *expression* which evaluates to 100. Note that `,` acts as the *expression separator operator* in this context.

`static_cast<cv::Rect>(100)` obviously fails.

There's no feasible way of using a `static_cast`, unless you're willing to enter the murky world of *user defined literals*. But even then, you'd have to tweak the syntax somewhat, and then you'd be able to drop the `static_cast` entirely.

Comment: "(100,100,100,100) is an expression which evaluates to 100" Make sense, thank you very much for the answer.